# Harddisk report low storage, but using only 25%

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I bought a ultrabook in Q1 this year that has 256Gb SSD in it. After 9 months of use, Windows shows 50Gb free disk space, but used is only 67Gb as shown below...

[image]
[image]

Where has all that free space gone?
**Note:** I included hidden files too in the report.

Comment: Disk Properties does not take into account the space used by Shadow Volume and File History.  Use a program of your choice to visualize the disk usage, and configure it to display all and unknown files, that should then match up with File Explorer.

Comment: Don't the drive's own properties show it's actual used & free space? Is the bottom properties from selecting a few visible files?